# Container_of() not compiling

Tags: c, linux, kernel, prefetch

List.h defines a macro called list_entry which is a wrapper for container_of() function.
An elegant function, which seems very delicate:

Consider this piece of code:

```
tmp = list_entry(pos,(struct Order),ord_Queue);
```

When I compile it using gcc, a constant error of expected expression is popping up.

My structure is defined as:

```
struct Order
        {
         double idNum;
         char* entryTime;
         char* eventTime;
         struct list_head ord_Queue;
        };
```

It seems there is a problem with container_of when there are superfluous brackets used in Arg2 and Arg3, and there should be one bracket only for Arg1 courtesy [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies@nl.linux.org/msg08921.html) . I have tried it, but it doesnt work.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the `(` and `)` around `struct Order`? As the compiler's telling you, struct Order is not an expression, and therefore can't arbitrarily be surrounded with ( and ) which - in the context of providing parameters to a function or macro - are only used to group subexpressions.

Comment: yes, I first started with precisely that, but it complained nevertheless. Then after reading the link given above I added the brackets. It still didnt compile. At the end, I tried doing away with that entire macro and tried using the same tailormade for the problem at hand(using fixed datatypes), still it didnt compile properly. At the end, it was giving a problem with prefetch. So yes,I tried the entire spectrum of possibilities which I could think.(Interestingly, when I did away with the macro and used its definition in my code, compiler kept complaining till everything was not bracketed)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is an error in `list.h` when you copied it from the kernel? (Assuming you are doing a userspace program here.) Because your example code (stripped a little more) does compile with a known-good implementation.

```
#include <libHX/list.h>
struct order {
        struct HXlist_head ord_queue;
};
int main(void) {
        struct HXlist_head *pos;
        struct order *o = HXlist_entry(pos, struct order, ord_queue);
}
```

Comment: I dont think the list.h in itself some problem, but there is definitely some problem with backcasting.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are missing the inclusion of "offsetof" macro as well, which is used by container_of() internally. Try including following code (instead of including whole list.h.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
             const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
             (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
  container_of(ptr, type, member)

struct list_head {
  struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

And there is no need of adding extra parenthesis in 2nd argument, it should work fine without it.
I hope this should work.

Comment: I needed to explain container_of to a coworker and this helped. (Was getting a compile error of "error: expected expression before ‘struct’" Adding the macro for offsetof and the header file sys/types.h fixed it. Thanks!